# syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Working through a code challenge where I have to add support to a "register". I've added the newly supported items as the following:

```
    require 'register'

require 'timecop'

describe Register do
  subject { described_class.new }

  describe 'Frozen Pizza' do
    it 'should be $5.00 each' do
      subject.ring_up('Frozen Pizza', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 5.00
      subject.ring_up('Frozen Pizza', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 10.00
    end
  end

  describe 'Corn' do
    it 'should be $0.50 each' do
      subject.ring_up('Corn', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 0.50
    end
    it 'should be 5 for $2.00' do
      subject.ring_up('Corn', quantity: 5)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 2.00
      subject.ring_up('Corn', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 2.50
    end
  end

  describe 'Ground Beef' do
    it 'should be $4.99/lb' do
      subject.ring_up('Ground Beef', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 4.99
    end
    it 'should allow partial pounds' do
      subject.ring_up('Ground Beef', quantity: 0.5)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 2.50
    end
  end

  describe 'Chocolate Mayfield Ice Cream' do
    it 'should be $5.99' do
      subject.ring_up('Chocolate Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 5.99
    end
    context 'on Wednesdays' do
      before { Timecop.freeze(Time.parse('2014-06-18 13:00:00')) }
      after  { Timecop.return }

      it 'should be BOGO' do
        subject.ring_up('Chocolate Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 2)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 5.99
        subject.ring_up('Chocolate Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 11.98
      end
    end
    context 'on Non-Wednesdays' do
      before { Timecop.freeze(Time.parse('2014-06-19 13:00:00')) }
      after  { Timecop.return }

      it 'should be NOT be BOGO' do
        subject.ring_up('Chocolate Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 2)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 11.98
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'Vanilla Mayfield Ice Cream' do
    it 'should be $5.99' do
      subject.ring_up('Vanilla Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 5.99
      subject.ring_up('Vanilla Mayfield Ice Cream', quantity: 1)
      expect(subject.total).to eq 11.98
    end
  end

  describe 'Mango' do
    context 'on Mondays' do
      before { Timecop.freeze(Time.parse('2014-06-16 13:00:00')) }
      after  { Timecop.return }
      it 'should be $0.50 each' do
        subject.ring_up('Mango', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 0.50
        subject.ring_up('Mango', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 1.00
      end
    end
  end

    context 'on Non-Mondays' do
      before { Timecop.freeze(Time.parse('2014-06-17 13:00:00')) }
      after  { Timecop.return }
      it 'should be $1.00 each' do
        subject.ring_up('Mango', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 1.00
        subject.ring_up('Mango', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 2.00
      end
    end


# Adding Additional Support To the Following Items

    describe 'Mahi Fillet' do
      it 'should be $7.99' do
        subject.ring_up('Mahi Fillet', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 7.99
        subject.ring_up('Mahi Fillet', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 15.98
      end
    end

    describe 'Mac & Cheese' do
      it 'should be $1.29 each' do
        subject.ring_up('Mac & Cheese', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 1.29
      end
        it 'should be 5 for $10.00' do
          subject.ring_up('Corn', quantity: 10)
          expect(subject.total).to eq 10.00
          subject.ring_up('Corn', quantity: 1)
          expect(subject.total).to eq 1.00
        end
    end

    describe 'Super Ripe Avacados' do
      it 'should be $1,10' do
        subject.ring_up('Super Ripe Avacados', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 1.10
      end

      it 'should be BOGO' do
        subject.ring_up('Super Ripe Avacados', quantity: 3)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 1.10
        subject.ring_up('Super Ripe Avacados', quantity: 1)
        expect(subject.total).to eq 0.36666666666667
      end
    end


end
```

Now I am creating some tests to run via Rake and commented as #Additions and after adding just one I get the Syntax Error and I'm completely stumped here.

```
    class Register
  attr :items

  def initialize
    @items = Hash.new(0)
  end

  def ring_up(item, args)
    @items[item] += args[:quantity]
  end

  def total
    total = 0
    items.each do |item, quantity|
      case item
      when 'Frozen Pizza'
        total += quantity * 5
      when 'Corn'
        if (quantity % 5 == 0) 
          total += quantity / 5 * 2.00
        else
          bundles = quantity / 5
          singles = quantity % 5
          total += bundles * 2.00 + singles * 0.50
        end
      when 'Ground Beef'
        total += (quantity * 4.99).round(2)
      when /Mayfield Ice Cream/
        if (quantity % 2 == 0) 
          if item =~ /^Chocolate/
            if Time.now.strftime("%A") == 'Wednesday'
              total += quantity / 2 * 5.99
            else
              total += quantity * 5.99
            end
          else
            total += quantity * 5.99
          end
        else
          if item =~ /^Chocolate/
            if Time.now.strftime("%A") == 'Wednesday'
              total += (quantity / 2) * 5.99 + (quantity % 2) * 5.99
            else
              total += quantity * 5.99
            end
          else
            total += quantity * 5.99
          end
        end
      when 'Mango'
        if Time.now.strftime("%A") == 'Monday'
          total += quantity * 0.50
        else
          total += quantity * 1.00
        end
      end

#Additions

      when 'Mahi Fillet'
        total += quantity * 7.99
      end 



    end
    total
  endNow 

end
```

The complete error return is the following:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
      when 'Mahi Fillet'
          ^
```

Comment: There is a `Now` next to the second-to-last `end`, you should remove it for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `end`:

```
  end  <<<<=====

#Additions

  when 'Mahi Fillet'
```

closes the whole `case` block and therefore the `when` in the next line doesn't make sense for the parser. Just delete that `end` to solve your problem.

Comment: This fixed the error, thank you! :)

Now I need to fix all of these failed tests lol.